# V8 installation in ubuntu

Tags: v8

I have followed the following steps to install v8 in ubuntu .No error occured during the process

```
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ./v8
cd v8
make builddeps
make native
```

but when I am trying to run the hello world program with the following command I'm getting error

```
 g++ -Iv8/include hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.o
v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a 

v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a -lpthread
```

The error is

```
g++: error: v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: No such file or directory
g++: error: v8/out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a: No such file or directory
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: _' No such file or directory'_ - you have files missing, or the paths you've used are wrong. The formatting of your command as you've posted it also looks supect, but that might be an artefact of your post.

Comment: post the folder structure where you are trying to execute the g++ command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just run the program using the following command !!

g++ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.o -lv8

:)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your folder structure it appears you are already in the v8 folder so try changing your command to this:

```
g++ -Iv8/include hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.o
out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a 
out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_snapshot.a -lpthread
```

Comment: Where are those files. Can you find them from the /home/geethu/v8 folder?

Comment: type the command `tree` in in the folder you are trying to execute the g++ script and paste the ouput here

Comment: There are sites you can post long text on, try to find one and post a link to it

Comment: You could just add it to your original post or try a site like http://freetexthost.com

Comment: Can you post all of it on a different website like http://textuploader.com/ or any listed in a google search https://www.google.com/search?q=free+text+hosting&oq=free+text+hosting&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3367j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8 ?